# Stackoverflow occurs on one IIS site but not another

Tags: iis-7

I have a website that has been hosted on a test site and I am now releasing it to a public facing demo site on IIS7. I first copied the website up to the Demo machine, created a seperate site and pointed it to my copied files. I logged into the site and performed a quick run through of the main functionality, all worked well. The config file is exactly the same as the existing Demo config except a few additional Application settings.

I then pointed the Demo site to my new Website folder. The old website folder was located at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DemoSite\10.5

The new one is at 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DemoSite\10.7

When I browse to the login page it appears. When I try to log in it hangs and eventually gives me a page cannot be found error. I checked the event logs and there are the following errors

```
Application: w3wp.exe

Framework Version: v4.0.30319

Description: The process was terminated due to stack overflow.


Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 7.0.6002.18005, time stamp 0x49e023cf, 
faulting module clr.dll, version 4.0.30319.269, time stamp 0x4ee9ae83, exception code
0xc00000fd, fault offset 0x00012f71, process id 0x%9, application start time 0x%10.
```

This must be something to do with IIS as I can log in with the same code in the same folder but with a different IIS site

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through all the IIS settings I noticed the Application pools had a different value for "Enable 32bit applications". I changed the setting on the Demo from YES to NO and it worked. My guess is that this was built on a 32 bit machine before, and now it is being built on an x64 processor.